Is it appropriate to utilize LSTMs for multivariate binary prediction on a timeseries by sliding block-by-block vs row-by-row?
I am trying to implement an ML algorithm for multivariate regression on a list of several timeseries. There are hundreds of timeseries, each one millions of rows long. There are 13 features, and I'm trying to predict three labels. One of the features is a textual string, for which I intended to either use an embedding layer which I will flatten later, or utilizing a mini-LSTM that will process the tokens. The timeseries features and labels are available in their entirety and there are not NA rows, and I would like to be able to predict the labels on non-previously-seen timeseries of a similar type. The labels are binary, 1s and 0s.
Due to the difficulty of the task, my initial target had become splitting up the timeseries into subsequences of fixed length, say 150, and predicting the labels for each subsequence, such that, in the end, I'm predicting tensors of shape (150, 3). The model I had come up with was the following:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class CombinedLSTMModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(
        self,
        token_vocab_size,
        token_embedding_dim,
        additional_feature_size,
        large_lstm_hidden_dim,
        large_lstm_num_layers,
        dropout,
        small_lstm_hidden_dim,
        output_dim=3,
    ):
        super(CombinedLSTMModel, self).__init__()
        
        # Embedding layer for token features
        self.token_embedding = nn.Embedding(token_vocab_size, token_embedding_dim)

        # Smaller LSTM for processing token embeddings
        self.small_lstm = nn.LSTM(
            input_size=token_embedding_dim,
            hidden_size=small_lstm_hidden_dim,
            num_layers=1,
            batch_first=True,
        )

        # Larger LSTM layer with bidirectional analysis
        self.large_lstm = nn.LSTM(
            input_size=small_lstm_hidden_dim + additional_feature_size,
            hidden_size=large_lstm_hidden_dim,
            num_layers=large_lstm_num_layers,
            batch_first=True,
            dropout=dropout,
            bidirectional=True,
        )

        # Fully connected layers
        self.fc = nn.Linear(large_lstm_hidden_dim * 2, output_dim)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, token_features, access_features):
        # Embed the token features
        embedded_tokens = self.token_embedding(token_features)

        # Process each token embedding with the smaller LSTM
        batch_size, sequence_length, encoding_length, embedding_dim = (
            embedded_tokens.shape[0],
            embedded_tokens.shape[1],
            embedded_tokens.shape[2],
            embedded_tokens.shape[3],
        )
        embedded_tokens = embedded_tokens.view(
            -1, encoding_length, embedding_dim
        )  # Flatten the batch and sequence dimensions for the LSTM
        small_lstm_out, _ = self.small_lstm(embedded_tokens)

        # Get the last hidden state of the small LSTM for each token
        small_lstm_last_hidden = small_lstm_out[
            :, -1, :
        ]  # shape: (batch_size * sequence_length, small_lstm_hidden_dim)
        
        small_lstm_last_hidden = small_lstm_last_hidden.view(
            batch_size, sequence_length, -1
        )  # Reshape back to (batch_size, sequence_length, small_lstm_hidden_dim)

        # Concatenate with access features along the feature dimension
        combined_features = torch.cat((small_lstm_last_hidden, access_features), dim=2)

        # Pass through larger LSTM
        large_lstm_out, _ = self.large_lstm(combined_features)

        # Pass through fully connected layer
        output = self.fc(large_lstm_out)

        return output

The thing is, due to the sheer volume of data, I changed the problem from sliding row-by-row across data, to setting up a  torch.utils.data.Dataset such that it returns non-overlapping equal length subsequence blocks, with each  __getitem__ returning X: (150, 13), y: (150,3) tensors. The criterion is BCEWithLogitsLoss.
I have been having mixed results with the validation loss (as measured on the holdout 12 timeseries), with it sometimes dropping slightly across a long training period and thus underfitting, and other times not budging, as dependent on the selected hyperparameters. I am utilizing Optuna on a reduced dataset for brevity to attain the parameters with the objective function optimizing for the normalized percentage drop in the validation loss across 5 epochs, combined with a ratio between validation loss and the training loss.
My question is, does there exist a better way than this for the task at hand, and in what direction I may go here? I am particularly interested in whether a row-by-row approach may be better, but perhaps on a reduced training dataset.
Any help is greatly appreciated, and I do apologize for any grave mistakes, as
I am relatively new to the field.
